# How to create a ratings csr_matrix in scipy?

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a csv file in this format :

```
userId  movieId rating  timestamp
1     31      2.5   1260759144
2     10      4     835355493
3     1197    5     1298932770
4     10      4     949810645
```

I want to construct a sparse matrix with rows as userId and columns as movieID.
I have stored all the data as a dictionary named "column"  where column['user'] contains user IDs, column['movie'] has movie IDs, and column['ratings'] has ratings as follows:

```
f = open('ratings.csv','rb')
reader = csv.reader(f)
headers = ['user','movie','rating','timestamp']
column = {}
for h in headers:
    column[h] = []
for row in reader:
    for h, v in zip(headers, row):
        column[h].append(float(v))
```

When I call the sparse matrix function as :

```
mat = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix((column['rating'],(column['user'],column['movie'])))
```

I get "TypeError: invalid shape"

Please help

Answer (score 1):

```
scipy.sparse.csr_matrix([column['rating'],column['user'],column['movie']])
```

You had a tuple consisting of a 1xn dimensional list, and a 2xn dimensional list which will not work.

P.S.: For the reading of the data, you should try Pandas :-) (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html). Minimal example:

```
import pandas as pd

# Setup a dataframe from the CSV and make it sparse
df = pd.read_csv('ratings.csv')
df = df.to_sparse(fill_value=0)
print(df.head())
```

Comment: this does not create a sparse matrix for row as users, column as movies and  [row,column] as  rating? How can we create a sparse matrix with user as rows, movies as column and the rating as value at [row,column] ?

Comment: The original command "mat = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix((column['rating'],(column['user'],column['movie'])))" was correct except that column['user'], column['rating'] and column['movie'] was to be converted to an array before using the function.

Answer (score 1):

check this way :

```
df = pd.read_csv('f:\\train.csv', usecols=[0, 1, 2], names=['userId ', 
                   'movieID', 'ratings'], skiprows=1)
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
utility_csr = csr_matrix((df.ratings, (df.userId , df.movieID)))
```